# sacar el numero de elementos de la clase de una etiqueta con javascript?

Tags: javascript

Quería saber como puedo sacar el número de elementos en `JavaScript` que función debería usar estuve buscando pero no encontré.
Ejemplo de código:

```js
var parentDOM = document.getElementById("parent-id");

var test=parentDOM.getElementsByClassName("test");//test is not target element
console.log(test);//HTMLCollection[1]

var testTarget=parentDOM.getElementsByClassName("test")[0];//here , this element is target
console.log(testTarget);//<p class="test">hello word2</p>
```

```html
<div id="parent-id">
    <p class="prueba">hello word1</p>
    <p class="test">hello word2</p>
    <p class="test">hello word3</p>
    <p class="test">hello word4</p>
</div>
```

Como puedo saber el número de elementos de la clase `test`. y sino es posible retornarlo en forma de lista y separarlo cada uno ¿Cómo podría ser?

Comment: `console.log(test.length);`

Answer (score 3):

Puedes obtener seleccionandolos con querySelectorAll, y como condicion el div(Padre) y la clase que quieres seleccionar.

```js
let cantidad = document.querySelectorAll('#parent-id .test').length;
console.log('cantidad:', cantidad);
```

```html
<div id="parent-id">
  <p class="prueba">hello word1</p>
  <p class="test">hello word2</p>
  <p class="test">hello word3</p>
  <p class="test">hello word4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: vale gracias ;)

Comment: @SergioRamos si te sirvio alguna respuesta, deberias marcarla como correcta

Answer (score 2):

Buen día, solo usa la función length de javascript, el resultado en este caso es 3.

```
<script>
    var parentDOM = document.getElementById("parent-id");

    var test=parentDOM.getElementsByClassName("test");//test is not target element
    console.log(test.length);//HTMLCollection[1]

    var testTarget=parentDOM.getElementsByClassName("test")[0];//here , this element is target
    console.log(testTarget);//<p class="test">hello word2</p>
</script>
```